# Solvable subgroup of group Aut(Zp+Zp)

Tags: group-theory

Is it true that for any Solvable subgroup $G$ of group $Aut(\mathbb{Z}_p\oplus\mathbb{Z}_p), G^{(4)} = \{e\}$? Is it true for subgroups of $Aut(\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{p^n})$?

My idea is to use Theorem $1.1$ (http://www.academia.edu/1816978/Subgroup_permutability_degree_of_PSL_2_p_n_), so is it helpfull and can we do same for case $Aut(\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{p^n})$?

Comment: I did a computer calculation, and it is not true for $p^n=27$.